# Split time string

Tags: jquery

OK, I've resisted to post this question but I can't explain the results I'm getting, so here it is:

I have get a time value in a military format, like 16:00. From this I need to get 3 different hours:

- An hour before the given,
- Given hour, and
- The hour following the given one

So expected result will be:

- 15
- 16
- 17

`

```
var timeRes = $(this).data('time'),
timeGet = timeRes.split(':'),
hourGet = timeGet[0],
minsGet = timeGet[1],
hourBfo = (hourGet-1),
hourNxt = (hourGet++);`
```

Seems pretty basic, however, when I test and out put the following:

```
console.log(timeRes+' -- Get: '+timeGet + ' -- Bfo: '+hourBfo+' -- Now: '+hourGet+' -- Nxt: '+hourNxt+' -- Mins: '+minsGet);
```

I get this:

> 16:00 -- Get: 16,00 -- Bfo: 15 -- Now: 17 -- Nxt: 16 -- Mins: 00

Notice, **Now** and **Nxt** are flipped. What am I missing?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 errors here. First, you should convert your splitted strings to integer, so there'd no strange effects while doing math operations with them:

```
hourGet = parseInt(timeGet[0]), minsGet = parseInt(timeGet[1])
```

Secondly, `hourNxt = (hourGet++)` works this way:

1. Assign current value of `hourGet` to `hourNxt`.
2. Increment `hourGet` value by 1.

That's why you're getting these results. You don't need `++` operator here (you don't want to change `hourGet`, do you?), just use plain old:

```
hourNxt = hourGet + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`hourNxt = (hourGet++);` basically means "set `hourNxt` to what `hourGet` currently is, and then increase the value of `hourGet` by one."

What you want is `hourNxt = hourGet + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
var time = '16:00';
var hour = time.split(':')[0];
var previousHour = hour - 1;
var nextHour = hour + 1;
```

The difference being if you use a ++ operator, you should learn how it works. It basically applies the increment after the command is done. So, the code:

```
var i=7;
console.log(i++);
console.log(i);
```

Will output:
    7
    8

I hope this helps.

Mario